# Why there's a text node between head and body nodes in DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm messing around with DOM tree. In particular with this HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>MovieApp</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>MovieApp</h1>
            <input type="text" name="movie-title" size="50" 
                placeholder="Enter movie title..." />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and there's something I'm not able to figure out. When I check  node children (`document.documentElement.childNodes[i]`) I always get three children instead of the two I was expecting to:

1. `<head>` node
2. **`#text`**
3. `<body>` node

What is this `#text` node? In [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7aq5y7o/3/) I'm getting same result.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: text node contains text . their are several nodes . you dont have to worry about

Comment: children(Element child) is only 2 but childnodes is 3

Comment: `nodeValue` in your screenshot tells you exactly what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `textContent` or other similar properties - it's a line feed and a few spaces, which is exactly between your `</head>` and `<body>`.

So there's nothing "useful" between `head` and `body`, but that space is still there.

Consider:

```
<div><a href="#">Some Link</a> Some Text <a href="#">Another Link</a></div>
```

This would have three nodes - the first link, the text, and the second link. Same deal, except your "text" is just a bunch of whitespace.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I was wondering about a non visible data structure or something similar and that was driving me crazy :P Actually I checked *nodeValue* and was, indeed, a bunch of spaces and so. Have a good weekend you all, guys.

Comment: LOL. I came across right now with these lines from Eloquent JavaScript (http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html#h_jS5BEpmLY0):

*Another complicating factor is that text nodes are created even for the whitespace between nodes. The example document’s body tag does not have just three children (<h1> and two <p> elements) but actually has seven: those three, plus the spaces before, after, and between them.*